# Is it possible to specify a unique file for incoming Syslog events?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog

I am using a propriety device which sends syslog events to a server. By default, these messages are ending up in /var/log/syslog. I am unable to configure a different file target on the device.

Is there a way to configure syslog so that external events are kept in a separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a centralized syslog server running [rsyslogd](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/), which should be default in Ubuntu as well. Apart from saving all syslog messages to MySQL, i have the following configuration to store them to individual files by hostname:

```
if $fromhost-ip != "127.0.0.1" then {
  $template remotelog,"/var/log/remote/%hostname%.log"
  *.* ?remotelog
  stop
}
```

This is written in [RainerScript](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/rainerscript/index.html), which should be included in your rsyslogd version since Ubuntu 14.04. Just paste it to your `rsyslogd.conf` file.